What English words derrive from "quaerere"?
What contemporary English words derive from "quaerere"?
It might help to know that querer is one of the more popular Spanish words for the English desire.
If it helps, then also consider the following list of inflections, conjugations, old Spanish and old French.
adquaerere
acquirere
aquerre
acquere 
acquire
qeroj
qua
quaer
quaere
quaerendo
quaerendus
quaerere
quaerimus
quaeris
quaerite
quaeritur
quaero
quaes
quaesi
quaestio
quaestor
quaestus
quendam
quere
querel
querer
querere
querir
querre
queurre
quod
quoi


The following are four words in common usage in the English language after the year 2000:


query
quest
question
acquire


There might be more than four words in English, but that is all that I could find at this time.

Some of these come to English from Latin words derived from the verb in question rather than directly from it. You might want to be more careful in phrasing both the question and the answer in this sense.

quaestor. If you search also for English words borrowed from Latin verbs with various prefixes, then besides acquire also conquer, inquire (enquire), require.

And then acquirement, acquisitive, acquisition, acquisitor, acquest, inquiry (enquiry), inquisitive, inquisition, inquisitor, inquest, requirement, requisitive, requisition, requisitor, request.

@Arfrever I like your comment. I recommend posting your comment as an answer to the question. If your answer garners more up-votes than my answer, then that would be ideal. I always enjoy reading stack exchange postings that have two or more responses, because the union of the responses together is usually more useful to learn from than one single response in isolation. I often right down a pre-liminary answer, so that there is somthing to read.

@Arfrever I am practicing my Spanish these days, so please forgive me for writing strangely..... A response of a quality below that which you have obtained the power to inscribe is majorly better than to learn from zero. Una respuesa de calidad debajo que tu tienes el poder para escribir es mas major que leer desde cero..... My point is that I hope you will post a better answer than I did. In a three-valued model we have no loaf of bread, half of a loaf of bread, and a whole load of bread. My answer represents half of a loaf of bread, which is better than no bread at all. Please post an answer
